# $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ a.e.$x$ implies $\mathrm{E}[f_n(X)] \to \mathrm{E}[f(X)]$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of measurable function $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f_n\to f$ a.e.x. $X$ is a random variable on probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$.

Then, expectation $\mathrm{E}[f_n(X)]$ converges to $\mathrm{E}[f(X)]$ in general?

In the case of $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ and $f_n$ is bounded, I think this is correct. But, I don't know in a.e.x convergence case.

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: The same obstructions as in dominated convergence theorem stand.

Comment: If suppose $f_n$ is bounded, $f_n\to f$ a.e.x implies $\mathrm{E}[f_n(X)]\to \mathrm{E}[f(X)]$?

Comment: To say "$f_n$ is bounded" is ambigus. Do you mean that the sequence $(f_n)$ is bounded or that the function $f_n$ is bounded for all $n$ ? For the first case, yes it hold, for the second case it does as my answer gives you a counter example. @sate

Comment: @surb that mean the second case. I'll see your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathcal P)=([0,1],\mathcal B[0,1],m)$ where $\mathcal B[0,1]$ is the Borel $\sigma -$algebra of $[0,1]$ and $m$ the Lebesgue measure. Take $f_n(x)=n\boldsymbol 1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x)$ and $X(\omega )=\omega $. Then $$f_n(x)\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0\quad \text{a.e.},$$
  but $\mathbb E[f_n(X)]=1 $ for all $n$.
- Nevertheless, if $f_n$ is uniformly bounded (i.e. there is $M>0$ s.t. for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $|f_n|\leq M$), then the result obviously hold by DCT as far as $$X\in\left\{x\in\mathbb R\mid \lim_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=f(x)\right\}\quad \text{a.s.}.$$
  For example, if $X$ has density, then the result hold.

Comment: If $f_n$ is uniformly bouded, why you can use DCT? In fact, in case $f_n(X)\to f(X)$ a.s you can use DCT. My question is that $f_n\to f$ a.e.x implies $f_n(X)\to f(X)$ a.s?

Comment: If there is $M>0$ s.t. $|f_n|\leq M$ for all $n$, since $M\in L^1(\Omega )$, you can use DCT. I don't understand the second question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, $M\in L^1(\Omega)$ is clear. But, in this case, $f_n(X)\to f(X)$ a.e.x, not $f_n(X) \to f(X)$ a.s. So, I don't know whether we can use DCT. I might be wrong, but I think  DCT could be applied in a.s convergence.

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea. Why is it that converge almost surely?

Comment: Indeed, it's not true (sorry for the mistake). You have to be sure that $X\in \{x\mid \lim_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=f(x)\}$ a.s.

Comment: Okay, thanks for answer.